# XNA: Extremely low textures quality on Windows XP Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, xna, windows-xp, virtualbox, xna-4.0

I have created 2D XNA game for Windows. I used XNA 4.0 Refresh with Visual Studio 2013.
On system where I created it(Windows 8.1), it runs great. I wanted to see how it runs on other systems, so I installed virtual Windows XP SP3 in VirtualBox. 
I installed everything I need (.NET Framework 4, XNA 4 Refresh Redistributable and VirtualBox DirectX video drivers).

Game starts. No exceptions(There were exceptions before I installed VirtualBox DirectX video driver). Music plays. But I can't see anything except plain purple background.

This is how it looked:
[image: This is how it looked]

And this is how it should look like:
[image: And this is how it should look like]

I have tested everything and now I am 99% sure what the difference exactly is. In Windows XP VM the game does not draw textures how it should. It takes the color of the first pixel and fills the texture rectangle with it. (All other from background textures in main menu have transparent color of first pixel.).

I think problem is not related to VirtualBox. My virtual machine has 128MB of video memory, 2d and 3d accelerations. Other non-XNA games run good on it.

Possibly the problem is in loading content.

I will be very grateful if anybody provides any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Imo you can't say anything for certain until you've tried it on a physical machine...

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Thanks for reply, but other DirectX non-XNA games work good, so the problem is probably not in VM.

Comment: That's my point. Maybe it's something in the XNA framework that requires a physical to function properly. I'm not saying that it is, I'm just saying it could be.